# Get Components class in Visual C# to put an image in the panel

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, class, components, console-application

I have a problem with creating a Components Class in a Forms application in Visual Studio 2010 with C#. Where I create a target for a game where you are supposed to thow a ball att the target.

There are no errors in this but the application can not be run, there just pops up an window saying "Bounce stoped working", "Windows is trying to find the problem..". If I remove the code of course the app runs totally fine.

So somthing is wrong, but Im not really shore what part thats wrong. Anyone have an idea?

Just ignore my swedish comments..

In my Component Class Target.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Bounce
{
 class Target : Label
 {
    public double targetPosX, targetPosY;

    public Target(Image image)
    {
        Image = image;
        BackColor = Color.Transparent; // Sätter bakgrundsfärgen till genomskinlig på kontrollen
        Size = new Size(205, 100); // Sätter storleken på kontrollen
        Visible = true; // Ser till att bollarna syns
    }

    public void ShowTarget()
    {
        targetPosX = Location.X;
        targetPosY = Location.Y;
    }

 }
}
```

The form bounce.cs in code (relevant part of the code):

```
       //Target

       Target target;

       target = new Target(Image.FromFile("images/target.png"));
       panel.Controls.Add(target);
       target.Location = new Point(100, 200);
       target.ShowTarget();
```

Comment: Did you single-step through your program? This way you might find out where (exactly) it crashes.

Comment: No acctually I didn't, but I dont really remember how so I just skipped it when Im very new at this at all, Hoped someone might see rightaway whats wrong ;) But its my next step about what to do acctually

Comment: So learn about setting breakpoints and stepping through your code. These are your friends!

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging

Comment: I will, but in the meantime, do you se whats the problem?

Comment: Yes you can, you just don't know how.

Comment: It dosen't seem to find the file.. but the file is where it stand it is.. so I dont really know why, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that your image path is invalid. It should be full path to image file. For example `"c:\someDirectory\Images\target.png"`

Comment: I found when I looked at the target that the target wasent nesserly directly wrong in the code, but it was some properties of the picture that I hade to change that had something to do with the path to the image i guess. 

Build Action - Content
Copy to outputdirectory - Copy if newer

Answer (score 0):

You set size to 205, 100 but Location to 100, 200

So Location is outside your rectangle...

Comment: That dosent really mather because the location is where it is located in the panel.